# With 2 ReLU activated layers, if the 2nd layer has all weights initialized to < 0, the network is always stillborn?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, relu

I've built on my own neural network library with keras-like syntax. I noticed that when using 2 consecutive ReLU activated layers, and the 2nd of those layers has its weights initialized to negative values, the network will always output the same value and can not learn?

Since ReLU output is always positive, with negative weights it seems like the 2nd layer always outputs 0 for every neuron for every sample. Is the only solution to use leaky ReLU? If my conclusion is correct, I wonder why ReLU is used at all with random weight initialization. Even if just a single ReLU activated neuron has only negative weights (instead of the entire layer), it seems to me like it will always output 0 and is thus useless. Would like to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Usually, neural networks are initialized by drawing from a distribution that is centered around 0. So weights will rarely be only negatives. Further, it is good practice to also scale your input feature to be zero-centered. So even in the rare scenario where you happen to randomly sample only negative values this should not matter.

Comment: Both the weights are centered around 0, and the input data is also standardized to be zero-centered. In my case the 2nd ReLU-activated layer has 4 weights, which were, by chance, all negative. The input features don't matter though, because the first ReLU-activated layer always has positive outputs.

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer but did not save it. Yes in this case you described all output will be zero and hence all subsequent layers output will also be zero. But after training this should be resolved

Comment: Training would not work. The gradient will be multiplied with the ReLU layer outputs, which results in 0. This is how i stumbled upon this dead ReLU issue, since the model sometimes would not learn at all.